# How to Unlock Android Screen From inside Service (Marshmallow)?

Tags: android, unlock, keyguard, android-studio-3.0

I am developing an app to schedule whattsapp messages. Curruntly i want to unlock screen and start whattsapp intent and send msg inside my service . I searched here and tried following solution. but both are depreciated.

**Method 1 (depreciated)**

`

```html
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

**Method 2 (depreciated)**

```html
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock"); 

kl.disableKeyguard(); 

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                             | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                             | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

I tried both methods but none seems to work.  **both Root and Noroot methods will work** 
 Please Help